# iPhone, trying to post a plist (NSDictionary) to a web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, plist, nsdictionary

Is there a simple way to package a plist object (`NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc.) and Post it to a web service?

Answer (score 1):

Sure; you can easily convert a plist object into XML using [`+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-BAJGGEJG) and then send the XML to your web service.